# Models for User relationship in Meteor/Mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to create a collection which is a User.
User has the following fields: is_dealer(boolean) and is_premium(boolean) and other user info like username, contact no. etc.
Now this user can either be a dealer or a client based on the is_dealer flag. I want to create list of all the dealers and the count of the clients they have as well as the no of premium clients they have. I tried this using aggregation on the server side, but meteor does not seem to support aggregations.

How do I go about modelling this collection, and how do I apply aggregations on client side for this. (Need not be reactive.).

Comment: Aggregations? Sounds like it's a simple count of the number of user docs that match your specifications, right?

Comment: Yes, but I want to be able to filter these docs based on conditions. What is the meteoric way to do this?

Comment: The docs are stored in a database. The database is MongoDB. Use a `find` and then a `count`. http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection

Comment: Also have a gander at the Mongo docs for all the CRUD methods and concepts: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations-introduction/